# Why does adding an onClick method cause an infinite loop in my react render method

Tags: reactjs

I have one line that seems to be causing an infinite loop.  The issue occurs if I assign an onClick handler to my element.

So, in a render function, the following causes an infinite loop

`button = <button onClick={ props.onLogin() }>Login</button>;`

In contrast, the following does not cause a loop

`button = <button>Login</button>;`

Full code

```
import React, { Component, PropTypes } from 'react';
import { login, logout } from '../actions/user';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';

class Navbar extends Component {

  render() {
    const props = this.props;
    const { user } = props;
    const { isAuthenticated, errorMessage } = user;

    let button;

    // the onClick assignment below causes the infinite loop
    if (isAuthenticated) {
      button = <button onClick={ props.onLogout() }>Logout</button>;
    } else {
      button = <button onClick={ props.onLogin() }>Login</button>;
    }

    return (
      <div>
        <a href="/">Hello</a>
        <div>
          <div>{errorMessage}</div>
          { button }
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }

}

Navbar.propTypes = {
  user: PropTypes.object,
  errorMessage: PropTypes.string,
};

const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
  return {
    user: state.user,
  };
};

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
  return {
    onLogin: () => {
      dispatch(login());
    },
    onLogout: () => {
      dispatch(logout());
    },
  };
};

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(Navbar);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to invoke the function inside the `onClick` attribute, just pass the function, so it has to be:

```
  // the onClick assignment below causes the infinite loop
  if (isAuthenticated) {
    button = <button onClick={ props.onLogout }>Logout</button>;
  } else
    button = <button onClick={ props.onLogin }>Login</button>;
  }
```

Comment: ah yes that's it!